# Does ListFragments not automatically restore dataset?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I have a fragment that extends ListFragment and when I minimize the app and go back to it, the listview is empty.

Does it not restore automatically?

```
public class LocationListViewFrag extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationListViewFrag";

    private ArrayList<LocationObj> mLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    private LocationAdapter mTaxAdapter;
    private LocationListViewListener mListener;

    @Bind(R.id.listLabel)
    TextView listLabel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mTaxAdapter = new LocationAdapter(getActivity(), mLocations);
        setListAdapter(mTaxAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tax_location_list, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (LocationListViewListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement LocationListViewListener");
        }
    }

    public void setLocations(ArrayList<LocationObj> Locations) {
        mLocations = Locations;

        mTaxAdapter.clear();
        mTaxAdapter.addAll(mLocations);
        mTaxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if(mLocations.isEmpty()){
            listLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            listLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        LocationObj aLocation = mLocations.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Clicked - %s", aLocation.toString()));

        mListener.onLocationSelected(aLocation);
    }

    public interface LocationListViewListener {

        void onLocationSelected(LocationObj LocationObj);

    }
}
```

Activity

`onCreate`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.free_tax_prep_providers_new);
        initDrawer();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Restore the fragment's instance
            mLocationListViewFrag = (LocationListViewFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mLocationListViewFrag");

        } else if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
            // the fragment_container FrameLayout

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            mLocationListViewFrag = new LocationListViewFrag();

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, mLocationListViewFrag).commit();

        }

    }
```

`onSavedInstance`

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        //Save the fragment's instance
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mLocationListViewFrag", mLocationListViewFrag);

    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setLocations`? I see the method declaration but it seems you haven't posted the method call.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin the Activity calls `setLocations` when it gets the data back from a web service. I didn't post it since I didn't think it would be relevant to the issue I am having

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you posted, it looks ok.. Try to debug it. Add an `onResume()` method to your list fragment and check whether the data is still there. At least to understand if it's empty because of rendering or because of no data.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually override onSaveInstanceState within the fragment itself instead of the activity. Doing that did the job for me when I was working with list fragments.